# What is more natural way to charge a cap or supercap?

Tags: capacitor, charging, dielectric-breakdown

Let's say I want to charge a capacitor with 25V rating to 20V.
It gives me a more options to do that:

1. Charging with series R.
2. Charging with series L.
3. Charging with current source (linear voltage ramp).
4. Some switched converter (not interested for me this time)

**Point 1)** causes high charging current at low cap voltage (0-12V) and low charging current at higher cap voltages(12-20V).
**Point 2)** causes low charging current at (0-3V), high charging current at (3-15V) and low charging current at (15-20V) (can overshoot of course).
**Point 3)** charges with constant current all the time.

What scenario is less harmful for capacitor?
Of course consider approx. same charging time in all points.
According my opinion it is not good to charge with high current at high cap voltages (10-20V) because the cap is getting closer to breakdown.

Comment: The clever money's on the switched converter unfortunately